# How to browse Bluetooth files to or from Windows® 10 without third party apps?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

On older Windows® *(including Windows 8.1®)* I could browse Bluetooth devices *(using the same hardware as today)* so I could choose where I was sending files on my phone. I could also browse the computer from my phone *(I always used my ᴘᴄ as my phone lack a true keyboard)*.
[image]
<sub>(source: [digitalcitizen.life](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/sites/default/files/img/bluetooth/blt4.png))</sub>

***Since Windows 10, the share tab does no longer exists in the Window above** (only 3 tabs remain)*.

My phone has 2 memory, and the first *(the default)* is only 2Mb large *(the second is micro sd)*. So If I send a file without browsing the phone *(in which directory I put it)*, then the file is rejected if it is larger than the memory used for storing sms *(the 2Mb memory)*.
Samsung confirmed there’s no way to change the default memory for receiving Bluetooth files.

Since the reorganization of the user interface on Windows® 10, I’m unable to find **how I can browse my phone over Bluetooth** *(it has only Bluetooth connectivity)*.
So I’m in the situation I can send only tiny files to my old java phone, as I only found how to pair the device or send files without browsing it.

Comment: no way to send via usb?

Comment: @Blaine : I have no idea on where to buy the ᴜꜱʙ converter nor what is the name of the custom port.

Comment: surely your phone charges via usb. what happens if you plug it into your computer

Comment: @Blaine : It doesn’t charge via ᴜꜱʙ. It’s an old ᴊ2ᴍᴇ samsung phone *(I tend to break Android or iᴘhone devices)*.

Comment: hmm, I can't seem to find a picture of the phone. could you send a picture of your charging port?

Comment: @Blaine : The connector is a s20pin one.  No local store provide it. And there should be no reason on why I shouldn’t be able to do obex Bluetooth on Windows®.

Comment: Even though some functionality may appear to be Windows-native, it could be provided by third-party software. This is often the case with Bluetooth features.

Comment: @DanielB : Yes, but this feature exists in all previous Windows® versions.

Comment: MSDN says otherwise. Like I said: It's hard to tell what's provided by third-party software (ie. your Bluetooth drivers). The drivers for Windows 10 are obviously a new version. They might have a different feature set.

Comment: @DanielB : Please post your ᴍꜱᴅɴ link. Even in Windows xp I could browse my device without third party apps *(it was always the same menu whatever the card is)*. The only exception was server versions. The driver of my Intel card was compiled in early 2014.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Microsoft removed the ability to natively mount your phone's file system in Windows 10 so you can browse it.

Previous versions of Windows had this ability, but it's gone now and most posts I see out there say you need a third party program to do it.

Someone alleged that this is because of some interface problem Microsoft was having, but the explanation was vague and seemed implausible to me. Essentially, the files weren't displaying cleanly. Again, that makes no sense considering the modular nature of the Windows interface.

Comment: Can you link some of them (either the posts or the software) please?!

Answer (score -3):

In Windows 10, bluetooth devices are accessible from Settings > Devices > Bluetooth. You can also hit start and type in "bluetooth," and navigate directly to Bluetooth settings from there.

Functionality beyond that point is going to be device-specific.

Comment: This doen’t answer the right question. I already know how to pair bluetooth devices.

Comment: He said it isn't part of Windows, like I did.

Comment: If your phone mounted like a removable drive before, then presumably it will mount upon connection now. That it doesn't indicates some difference in drivers between your old OS and your new one. As Daniel and I are trying to say, it depends. You may have substantially better luck reviewing documentation related to your specific device.

Comment: @BradleyEvans : I definitely can’t see how this is related to my now unsupported by intel bluetooth card.

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with your PC's bluetooth card and everything to do with drivers related to your mobile device's bluetooth.

Comment: @BradleyEvans : sorry, but do you mean the phone ? I never installed drivers for it. Everything I had to do is to pair it with bluetooth. From there, if it didn’t appeared in the Windows® explorer, I could sill [set up folder sharing on the ᴘᴄ](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/sites/default/files/img/bluetooth/blt4.png).

Comment: @DanielB : do you rather mean it is **no longer** part of Windows® ? I can’t see why they would have removed the feature. There were a lot of change in the ᴜɪ like how to install optional windows updates. So *(without official documentation)* I just think it moved elsewhere.